# give dynamic action name in Url.action javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

I want to give dynamic action name in Url.action through javascript.

```
// I want to change Index name by dynamic
      $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', 
                        type: "Post",
                        data: { Surveyid: surveyid, Category: catcode },
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = data.Url
                        }
```

like

**var x="xxxx";**

```
@Url.Action(x,"Home") -> not working throws error

@Url.Action(x.toString(),"Home") -> not working
```

then how can i ?

Comment: Is "x" client variable or server variable? If "x" is client variable, you cant use it in server code (in Url.Action)

Comment: no everything is clientside only.i meant x and url.action everything in clientside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Url.Action` is server generated, whereas it seems you want to change the action on the browser. What you can do is tokenize the Action, get `Url.Action` to generate the tokenized URL, and then substitute this in js:

```
var jsUrl = '@Url.Action("##", "Home")'; // ## is the token
$.ajax({
    url: jsUrl.replace('##', someDynamicAction),
    ...
```

(You may need to do the same for the controller)

**Edit**

My conscience has gotten the better of me - doing this isn't a good idea, given that any invalid action name (or a change in the `Controller` or `Action` names) will only be picked up at run time e.g. with 404 errors.

The number of controllers and actions that you need to ajax to should be finite, and [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation) has already solved this kind of issue.

You can create the urls to the various links:

```
var urlToIndex = '@Url.Action(MyControllerAssembly.Index.Home())))';
var urlToOtherAction = ...
... etc for all actions needed in the 'switch' for ajax call.
```

and then choose the appropriate URL for your ajax call. (T4MVC also has methods `Url.JavaScriptReplacableUrl` and `Ajax.ActionLink` although for slightly different scenarios)

Answer (score 3):

Best way to use urls in your mvc application is that you define a global app_url in layout page like following:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script>
    var app_root = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

and use in content page

**any_page that inherited from _Layout.cshtml**

```
 $.ajax({
     url: app_root + 'Home/Index', // or url: app_root + 'Home/' + x
```

Answer (score 0):

something odd in your example, but I believe what you are trying to do is this

```
function axajThis(numberthing,path) {

    var newUrl = "htttp://somplace/"+path; 
     /* and what ever the number x is doing */
      $.ajax({
         url: newUrl, 
         type: "Post",
         data:  .... 
       });
    };
 }

 axajThis(x,"Home");
```

Little more info needed on what 'x' is.